# How can I pass a datatable to an event handler as additional parameter

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable

On my form there is a combobox that is databound, and two date time pickers.
I am trying to pass the datatable to my cbo_SelectedIndexChanged() handler so when the user selects the second value in the combobox, the date time pickers will have their text bound from the datatable.

I am wondering how to do this and also what is the cleanest method of doing so.

```
Private Sub cboTrainType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboTrainType.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=VERITON-005\HR_SQL;Initial Catalog=HR235;User ID=sa;Password=HRSQL@235")
        sqlConn.Open()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_SelectAllTraining")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.SelectCommand.Connection = sqlConn

                da.Fill(dt)
                sqlConn.Close()
                cboEditEmpDept.DisplayMember = "Type"
                cboEditEmpDept.ValueMember = "TrainingID"
                cboEditEmpDept.DataSource = dt
                cboEditEmpDept.Text = ""
            End Using
            sqlConn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using

    Dim selectedindex = cboTrainType.SelectedIndex
    dtpTrainDate.Text = dt.Rows(selectedindex)("trainingDate").ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't pass the datatable to your selectedindexchanged eventhandler. You can grab the datasource from a field in the eventhandler or cast the sender to the combobox and grab the datasource from there.

Comment: this is what I meant by passing the datatable to the event handler when you said grab the datasource from a field in the event handler. I want to add an additional parameter to the event handler then pull the information I need

Comment: `How can I pass a datatable to an event handler as additional parameter` you cant.  The DTP is compiled and coded to do what it does how would it know where to get the DT or even that it was supposed to do so?  Kind of confusing how a DTP factors into a CBO event.

Comment: My train of thought was load the form, bind the combobox with the data I need and then whenever the selectedindex changed I wanted to update the value in these date time pickers accordingly.

I could make a call to the database each time the user changes the selectedindex but to me that is bad design and waaaay too many calls to the database so I am trying to find a workaround for that

Comment: You cant add a parameter to the eventhandler because the eventhandler type can not be changed. You can wrap the eventhandler in an custom eventhandler but this required also a field. I can't think of a situation why you need this. Perhaps some code?

Comment: look at previous comment please to understand what I am trying to achieve here. I have only the databind on each SelectedIndexChange as a solution thus far and I do not want to use that right now.

Comment: The controls (be it DTP or CBO) arent going to know to bundle your *runtime* object into their private, generic event, and arent going to violate the `sender, e` signature just for you.  Whatever you are trying to do, there are better ways

Comment: I must just be asking this question wrong. the user selects a value in the combobox then I want the information to be retrieved from the datatable for the specific row (using the ID), then set the .text property of the datetimepicker.

Comment: Whats stopping you from accessing the DT in any event you need?

Comment: it just says the object is inaccessible I posted code in the question to show what I am trying to do but my code example is incorrect as I do not want to be making a call to the database each selectedindexchanged

Comment: This is an XY problem.  Declare the DT at the form level (outside any method or event) and it will be available everywhere.  As is, it has local `Scope`.  You'll need to check if it is Nothing in some cases/places in case the user doesnt do things in exactly the order you anticipate.

Comment: this will work I have done this with a few variables (ID's I needed elsewhere in code) I wish I could remote in and change my code now, ah well best saved for the morning. Thanks Plutonix